# Dynamic spacing between controls in the Toolbar in WPF

Tags: wpf, toolbar

I have a toolbar which contains several controls, say 10.

I want to place last three controls in the right corner of the tool bar with some space between these three controls and remaining controls.

When I resize the window, it should reduce the space, once there is no space it should be cliped to overflow drop down one by one.

Note: I need to use only one toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once before

The items existed in a customized `ScrollViewer` so they could go off-screen, and the `SizeChanged` event of the `ScrollViewer` would check each item to see if it was off-screen or not. If it wasn't visibile, or was partially visible, then the item would get hidden and the data object would get added to a `Menu`. If the item was visible, it would remove it from the `Menu` if it existed there, and set it visible. The `Menu` was only visible if it had items.

This was done a while back when I was still new to WPF, so I'm sure the process could be improved on.

The helper class I used to determine item visibility is listed below

```
public static ControlVisibility IsObjectVisibleInContainer(FrameworkElement child, UIElement parent)
{
    GeneralTransform childTransform = child.TransformToAncestor(parent);
    Rect childSize = childTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(child.Width, child.Height)));

    Rect result = Rect.Intersect(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), parent.RenderSize), childSize);
    if (result == Rect.Empty)
    {
        return ControlVisibility.Hidden;
    }
    else if (result.Height == childSize.Height && result.Width == childSize.Width)
    {
        return ControlVisibility.Full;
    }
    else if (result.Height == childSize.Height)
    {
        return ControlVisibility.FullHeightPartialWidth;
    }
    else if (result.Width == childSize.Width)
    {
        return ControlVisibility.FullWidthPartialHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        return ControlVisibility.Partial;
    }
}

public enum ControlVisibility
{
    Hidden,
    Partial,
    Full,
    FullHeightPartialWidth,
    FullWidthPartialHeight
}
```

It could be used like this:

```
ControlVisibility itemVisibility = 
    MyHelpers.IsObjectVisibleInContainer(someItem, parentContainer);
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Syed I'm sure there is, but this is just the way I did it.